# How can I push the same object to an array N times but be different objects in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I have this object below, where IMemberCard is an interface.

```
const memberCard: IMemberCard = { id: null, name: 'Member', rating: null, photoUrl: '/assets/images/user.png', type: null, eventCount: null, experienceLevel: null, years: null, certification: null, isPriority: null, memberStatus: null, receiveNotification: null};
```

**Question** - Is there a way to push() N of these objects into the array and make them different objects but with these values?

I know this works with a loop but aren't they the same object?

```
const memberCardArray: IMemberCard[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.yogaband.members; i++) {
   memberCardArray.push(memberCard);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want literally *the same* object added to the array multiple times? Or do you want multiple *different* objects that have the same values?

Comment: Different objects with the same values.

Answer (score 1):

if it is always the same reference to memberCard, you can do this:

```
const memberCardArray: IMemberCard[] = [];
memberCardArray = Array.from({length: this.yogaband.members}).map(()=> memberCard);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your `[all the objects]` look and what the detailed requirements are, you could use one of these methods:

- `splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, itemN)` if you have individual different items to add
- `fill(value, start, end)` to add the same value multiple times to the array
- `concat(value0, value1, ... , valueN)` to concatenate multiple arrays - the values here are arrays! Take care this method does not modify the original array where you call it from, but rather returns a new array.

Find a detailed reference on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

```
const memberCard: IMemberCard = { id: null, name: 'Member', rating: null, photoUrl: '/assets/images/user.png', type: null, eventCount: null, experienceLevel: null, years: null, certification: null, isPriority: null, memberStatus: null, receiveNotification: null};

const getNMemberCards = (n, mc): IMemberCard[] => Array(n).fill({ ...mc })

const result: IMemberCard[] = IMemberCard(5, memberCard)
```

Code example:

```js
const memberCard = { id: null, name: 'Member', rating: null, photoUrl: '/assets/images/user.png', type: null, eventCount: null, experienceLevel: null, years: null, certification: null, isPriority: null, memberStatus: null, receiveNotification: null};

const getNMemberCards = (n, mc) => Array(n).fill({ ...mc })

const result = getNMemberCards(5, memberCard)

console.log(result)
```